# React Native Audio Video Calling

Tags: javascript

i want to make audio and video call just like whatsapp a user can click on the phone logo to make an audio call and same goes for the video call, is there any other library other than voximplant and webrtc, thanks in advance

Comment: If you want *any other library other than voximplant and webrtc* then say why. Please read [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question.

Comment: have you completed implementation of VoxImplant now? I need some help regarding same. :)